# Model file name changes the table name in database

Tags: laravel

Hello i have a table called `order_product` that i want to get values from it and the model for that table called `order_product` with values:

```
public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'product_id',
        'amount',
    ];
```

This is the code of the model `Order` :

```
public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'order_number',
        'client_id',
        'description',
    ];


    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(order_product::class);
    }
```

A professional guy helped me and explained to me how the relation worked so the `client` and `products` work very good but the `orders` makes error in the sql.

This is the code im executing in the controller:

```
$orders = Order::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
$orders->load('client', 'products','orders');
```

The error that i get is:

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user_project_db.order_products' doesn't exist**

What should be the name of the file `order_product` so the query can execute properly?

Comment: what is the name of your `order_product` model?

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi its order_product

Comment: then in that case inside you order_product model add this `protected $table = 'order_product'` or `protected $table = 'order_products'` bacause your modal is not finding the table inside your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change my answer after reading your answers below.

Your table relationship is `orders` - `order_product` - `products`.

https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/
under **Pivot tables**

The way you named your pivot table is already correct.

`order_product` is to connect `orders` to `products` in a many-to-many.

So i think you can try to do the following.

Inside model Product add this relationship.

```
public function orders() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'order_product');
}
```

And in model Order add the other connection

```
public function products() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_product');
}
```

`belongsToMany` accepts 2 parameter, 1st is model destination, and 2nd is table pivot name, in your case `order_product`.

With this , an extra model OrderProduct is optional.

To add a product into order , you can use attach

```
 $order = Order::find($order_id);
 $order->products()->attach($product_id);
```

Or if you have extra fields within pivot table

```
// first implement this change inside Order model

return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_product')
   ->withPivot('price', 'qty');

// to attach for example price and qty
$order->products()->attach($product_id, ['price' => 200', 'qty'=> 1]);
```

To query the price

```
$order_product = $order->products()
   ->where('product_id', $product_id)
   ->first()->pivot;
$price = $order_product->price;
$qty = $order_product->qty;
```

And back to your own query.

No need to add orders() inside Order model.

And load only the first 2 relationship should be enough.
`$order->load('clients', 'products');`

Comment: i did that and still doesnt work i have my model called `OrderProduct` the database table is called `order_product` and when i execute the code i get this error `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'user_project_db.order_order_product' doesn't exist ` it adds an extra `order` in front of `order_product` how can i fix this?

Comment: inside OrderProduct , have you set the table name `protected $table = 'order_product';` , and if still not working , can you verify using phpmyadmin or adminer that table `order_product` does exists ? if still not working, check your .env configuration , correct DB_HOST ? and that you not using testing database ?

Comment: also have you read this article https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/ , you might best to change table name to `order_products`

Comment: yes i did also add the `protected $table='order_product';` im using *datagrip* as database manager and the table does exist.

Comment: if i change the table to order_products 2 other working functions wont work at all

Comment: @KGG the model file name still makes a problem to access the `order_product` table

Comment: so you database is `user_project_db` ? is this correct ? did you run laravel using serve / browser or using artisan test ? cause test using different database

Comment: by the way , inside public function orders , i notice you use `belongsToMany (order_product::class)` , have you change it to your new model name `belongsToMany (OrderProduct::class)` ?

Comment: yes thats the name of database, i run laravel using serve

Comment: yes i did change it

Comment: I add extra note to my answer, this is another way to connect Order to Product in many-to-many relationship, this might be another solution for you.

Comment: i have used the attach and works the table `order_product` is filled but when i want to get those data to show or delete it makes error with the name

Comment: if you use attach , you do not need relation orders() inside Order , you already have products() , so change your query to `$orders->load('client', 'products');`

Comment: so how do i get values from `order_product`  table?

Comment: this is so confusing because if i do `{{$products->amount}}` i will get the amount from table products not from table `order_products`

Comment: this is correct, so what you need to do `$product->pivot->amount`, this will get data from you pivot table 'order_product'

Comment: i get this `Attempt to read property "amount" on null` do i need to declare pivot somewhere in the model of `Order`?

Comment: just dont forget to add in your relationship product() `belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('amount', 'price', 'qty');` as many pivot fields as you needed

Comment: okay i will add it now

Comment: still isnt working can we enter a chat here to show you this part of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251544/discussion-between-laracoder-and-win).

Comment: almost forgot , https://www.amitmerchant.com/attach-detach-sync-laravel/, about attach and detach , be very careful when use `detach()` because empty `detach()` can **delete all of your data in order_product related to selected order_id**

Answer (score 0):

`protected $table = 'order_products;` in the model will tell Laravel that the `Order` model's data is stored in a table by that name.

However, typically you'd have an Order model, a Products model, and a *pivot table* (potentially with a pivot model, if you need it) titled `order_products`. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

Comment: i tried the `protected $table = 'order_products;` but didnt work i noticed that the name of database changed on the error when the name of file changed.